# При переходе на анкорную ссылку - перебрасывает вверх

Tags: javascript

При переходе или открытии в браузере анкорной ссылки - сайт поднимается сразу же вверх. Я если честно уже даже не знаю как загуглить такое, перепробовал все варианты, но в любом случае когда я открываю сайт по ссылке: https://planeandotuexito.com.mx/#contacto - меня сразу же бросает вверх. Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать, чтобы хоть немного понять, почему такое действие?

Comment: Когда dom подгружается, то срабатывает прокрутка наверх. Там jquery, скорее всего вызывается в этом месте $(document).ready()

Comment: Да и он вызывается вне зависимости - стоит ли якорь или нет.